# Response with js in scroll load more feature but any js is not working

Tags: javascript, php

**I'm sending the response from laravel with tags and have a js function that loads on scroll that doesn't seem to work. Could someone spot the issue? Here's my code**

```
$html .= '<a v-on:click.prevent="viewLogin()" href="">'. $d->companyname .'</a>';
```

Comment: every thing is working fine but only vue js from here is not working while vue js function is working while loading data first time. but when it scroll down and loads more data then js stops working for load more data which is populated from ajax response

Comment: The question is a bit vague and hard to understand. Can you please re-check and try to submit it again. You can check a guide on this matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
thanks.**i found the solution here:**
*actually after ajax response onclick property will not work because it was already loaded in browser reload so we need to add onclick property again.*


  $(document).on("click", "a.login", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');

    });
```